# ABC sorting T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a select output with this column, that has about 318 rows

```
skiped_times
-----------
        967
        967
        244
        153
        125
        116
        116
        116
        116
        116
        116
         98
         94
         89
         73
         73
         72
         66
         61
         60
         60
         60
         60
         60
         55
         48

...
```

The sum value of this column is about 6 100 and I want to another column sort these values into 3 groups, where for example in group A will be the first 20 % rows of counted values, in group B 30 % and in C the rest

I hope you understand my question

Comment: Do you want 20% by count of records or 20% by sum of the values?

Comment: What's the expected results?

Comment: I tried NTILE () but this in not what I want

ALso This 
,CASE 
  WHEN T5.skiped_times >= suma THEN 'A'
  ELSE 'B'
  END AS 'ABC'

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen - better will be the 20 % by sum of the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum < num * 0.2 as 'A'
             when seqnum < num * 0.5 as 'B'
             else 'C'
        end) as grp
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (order by skiped_times desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as num
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note:  The use of `rank()` means that values with ties are placed in the same group.  If they can split between groups, then use `row_number()`.

EDIT:

If you want this by the *sum* of values -- well, first you should be clear in the question, not in a comment.  You can use the same idea:

```
select t.*,
       (case when running_sum < total * 0.2 as 'A'
             when running_sum < total * 0.5 as 'B'
             else 'C'
        end) as grp
from (select t.*,
             sum(skiped_times) over (order by skiped_times desc) as running_sum,
             sum(skiped_times) over () as total
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my friend.. You gave me a good training for this question.

Hear is a solution. I hope this work for you

```
Declare @Percent20 int
Declare @Percent30 int

set @Percent20 = (select count(skiped_times) from TABLE_NAME) * 0.20

select @Percent20
set @Percent30 = (select count(skiped_times) from TABLE_NAME) * 0.30
select @Percent30


select 
ID,

(Case 
when exists(select result.skiped_times where result.skiped_times in (select top (@Percent20) skiped_times from TABLE_NAME order by skiped_times ))
then 'A'
when  Exists(select result.skiped_times where result.skiped_times in (select top (@Percent30) skiped_times from TABLE_NAME order by skiped_times ))
then 'B'
when  Exists(select result.skiped_times where result.skiped_times in (select skiped_times from TABLE_NAME order by skiped_times offset (@Percent30) rows ))
then 'C'

end

) as Per
 from (

select 
s.skiped_times from TABLE_NAME  s

 ) as result

 order by result.skiped_times
```

Comment: Is there a condition to this that I have to separate all data to some table? I never work with declaration before

Comment: Do you use ms-sql ? And where do you use this sql code ? in a program or in sql server job,view or anything else